# Is this true for biconditional statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

Given

A = At least ten people are there

L = Lecture will be given

Does A $\iff L$ means that lecture will be given only when at least ten people are there, means there cannot be other reason for lecture to be given and nothing else. And if ten people are not there then lecture will not be given at any cost.

Is this true ?

Comment: Yes, this is meant with "$\iff$" , which means "if and only if".

Comment: Yes, and if the lecture is given, then it is true that at least 10 people are there.

Comment: It's more easy think about when there are same words in proof and conditions: for example words "reason", "cost" are not in formulation of sentences.

Comment: You can always reframe a biconditional as two conditionals going either way. So $A\iff L$ means that both $A\rightarrow L$ and $L\rightarrow A$, i.e., "if there's at least 10 people there *then* a lecture will be given" and "if a lecture is given *then* there are at least 10 people there".

Comment: Thank you. So biconditional eliminates that possibility that P being false (other reasons than P)and Q being true ? Right

Comment: Similar to what zkutch says, I'd avoid using "reason" here. It isn't that $A$ and $L$ necessarily *make* each other happen, it's just that they happen together.

Comment: Yes, you're right that it is impossible for $P$ to be true and $Q$ to be false if we know $P\iff Q$.

Comment: @Jam But it looks like it means that , A and L  make each other happen ?

Comment: per definition of "$\ \iff\ $" , $\ A\ $ and $\ L\ $ must be both true or both false. Only then is $\ A \iff L\ $ true. This does not mean that $\ A\ $ causes $\ L\ $ or vice versa. If $\ A\ $ is true and $\ L\ $ false or vice versa, then we just do not have $\ A\iff L\ $

Comment: @JessicaGriffin Maybe, however that is not exactly true. For instance, consider the statement "if it is snowing, then it has to be cold outisde". So in this case, the presence of snow implies cold, but the snow did not *cause* the cold.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But this is not biconditional statement

Comment: @JessicaGriffin It's sort of tangential to the question and semantics so I wouldn't get  too hung up on it. But you can imagine two things that happen to be true at the same time but aren't "causing" each other. Like "I **only** ever drink coffee and eat cookies at the same time". If I'm drinking coffee you know I'm eating cookies and vice versa, so they're *true* together. But it's not like one is causing the other.

Comment: @Jam Good example !

Comment: @Jam Thanks i see

Answer (score -2):

1. Material biconditional (symbol $X \leftrightarrow Y$) contains no idea of possibility or impossibility. It only means that, as a matter of fact, propositions $X$ and $Y$ do not have different truth values, that is, that they are either both true or both false. So as soon as (for a reason or another) the lecture is given and (for a reason or another) there are at least $10$ people, it is true that  $L \leftrightarrow A$.

   Note: both material implication and bi-implication are very poor statements as to their informational contents
2. Logical equivalence (symbol: $\iff$, or $\equiv$) is more demanding. It requires not only that $X$ and $Y$ have the same truth value, but also that $X$ and $Y$ cannot possibly have different truth values. Or, if you prefer, it requires that $X$ and $Y$ have necessarily the same truth value.

   So $X \iff Y$ standardly means that the material biconditional $X \leftrightarrow Y$ is always true, in all (logically) possible cases.
3. Normally, the kind of possibility / necessity invoked here is a logical one. But, in the example you take, it seems the necessity is more of a "legal" sort. The case you are considering is: "due to the rules of the university,

   (a) the fact that there are at lest 10 students is necessarily a sufficient condition for the lecture to be given

   and

   (b) the fact that there are at least 10 students is necessarily a necessary condition for the lecture to be given".

Reference: Seymour Lipschutz, *Schaum's Outline Of Set Theory* (the chapter on the "Algebra Of Propositions"), at archive.org.

Comment: If you want to split hairs between "⇔" and "↔" you had better make it **very clear** that you are only talking about a **specific convention** that is not at all followed by everyone. Otherwise you are just setting the asker up for confusion. Secondly, it is a very bad idea to quote Schaum's anything, because most of them are poor quality.